# FlinkCEP pattern detection doesn't happen in real time

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-cep

I'm still new to Flink CEP library and yet I don't understand the pattern detection behavior.
Considering the example below, I have a Flink app that consumes data from a kafka topic, data is produced periodically, I want to use Flink CEP pattern to detect when a value is bigger than a given threshold.
The code is below:

```
public class CEPJob{
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
        properties.setProperty("group.id", "test");

        FlinkKafkaConsumer<String> consumer = new FlinkKafkaConsumer<String>("test", new SimpleStringSchema(),
                properties);

        consumer.assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(WatermarkStrategy.forMonotonousTimestamps());

        DataStream<String> stream = env.addSource(consumer);

        // Process incoming data.
        DataStream<Stock> inputEventStream = stream.map(new MapFunction<String, Stock>() {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = -491668877013085114L;

            @Override
            public Stock map(String value) {
                String[] data = value.split(":");

                System.out.println("Date: " + data[0] + ", Adj Close: " + data[1]);

                Stock stock = new Stock(data[0], Double.parseDouble(data[1]));

                return stock;
            }
        });

        // Create the pattern
        Pattern<Stock, ?> myPattern = Pattern.<Stock>begin("first").where(new SimpleCondition<Stock>() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = -6301755149429716724L;

            @Override
            public boolean filter(Stock value) throws Exception {
                return (value.getAdj_Close() > 140.0);
            }

        });

        // Create a pattern stream from our warning pattern
        PatternStream<Stock> myPatternStream = CEP.pattern(inputEventStream, myPattern);

        // Generate alert for each matched pattern
        DataStream<Stock> warnings = myPatternStream .select((Map<String, List<Stock>> pattern) -> {
            Stock first = pattern.get("first").get(0);

            return first;
        });

        warnings.print();

        env.execute("CEP job");
    }
}
```

What happens when I run the job, pattern detection doesn't happen in real-time, it outputs the warning for the detected pattern of the current record only after a second record is produced, it looks like it's  delayed to print to the log the warining, I really didn't understand how to make it outputs the warning the time it detect the pattern without waiting for next record and thank you :) .

Data coming from Kafka are in string format: "date:value", it produce data every 5 secs.

Java version: 1.8, Scala version: 2.11.12, Flink version: 1.12.2, Kafka version: 2.3.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found that to send a fake record (a null object for example) in the Kafka topic every time I produce a value to the topic, and on the Flink side (in the pattern declaration) I test if the received record is fake or not.
It seems like FlinkCEP always waits for the upcoming event before it outputs the warning.